# Is is Possible to have nested Context Menus in Sublime Text 2/3?

Tags: contextmenu, sublimetext

Sublime Text's Context menu has a few default items like Copy,Cut,paste, Select all etc... I know that we can add/remove items via configuration but can we have nested menus(menus within menus) like the one we have in chrome or notepad++.

[image: Context Menu in Notepad++]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not fully understand your question, we surely can customize our context menu with nested menus(menus within menus), all we need to do is creating a "Context.sublime-menu" file under "Packages\User" folder, make create customized menu items like this:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "-",
        "id": "separator"
    },
    {
        "caption": "First Level Menu",
        // "mnemonic": "f",
        "id": "firstlevelmenu",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "command": "Command1",
                "caption": "command1"
            },
            {
                "command": "Command2",
                "caption": "command2"
            },
            {
                "caption": "Second Level Menu",
                "children":
                [
                    {
                        "command": "Command3",
                        "caption": "command3"
                    },
                    {
                        "command": "Command4",
                        "caption": "command4"
                    }
                ]
            },            
        ]
    },
    {
        "caption": "-",
        "id": "separator"
    }
]
```

Keyword "children" is the one to create sub-menus.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the default menu was a flat one and I did not have enough knowledge of json to know about the "children" keyword.